# Need a way to post a url to facebook than will display html in the preview and then redirect

Tags: php, redirect

Need a way to post a url to facebook than will display html in the preview and then redirect to a page.  The problem is that I also have a php tag that I need to pass.

Right now I'm using a normal 301 header redirect but then you cant output any html.  As a result, the facebook preview of the link/page looks blank.  So what I want to do is have some html output for facebook to pick up and display and interrogate what is in $search if there is anything and then redirect based on that.

```
<?php

$search=urlencode($_GET['search']);

if ( $search == "" )
{
$redirectlink="http://mylink";
}
else
{
$redirectlink="http://mylink$search";
}

header("Location: $redirectlink", true, 301);
exit;
?>
```

Comment: Facebook doesn't let you show HTML in link previews. If you want to present OG tags, you can detect the Facebook crawler's user agent (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/crawler#identify) and serve it something different.

Comment: So how do you do that inside of my current code?  Do I need to just switch to html redirects?